# innerHTML tag option doesn't work in IE9

Tags: javascript, html

My code:

```
    this.d.innerHTML = "";
    this.d.innerHTML += "<option value='-1'>Selecciona Distrito</option>";
    this.d.innerHTML += "<option value='santiagodesurco'>Santiago de Surco</option>";
    this.d.innerHTML += "<option value='sanborja'>San Borja</option>";
    this.d.innerHTML += "<option value='independecia'>Independencia</option>";
    this.d.innerHTML += "<option value='miraflores'>Miraflores</option>";
    this.d.innerHTML += "<option value='santanita'>Santa Anita</option>";
```

The problem is that the select tag in IE9 the tag option is ignored check it out:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IolyV.png

But in Chrome the tag option is displayed:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfbDS.png

That's my problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a known bug in IE: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;276228

Comment: I suggest using DOM to create SELECT and its options

Comment: As a general rule, I'd suggest building the string and setting the `innerHTML` property **once**. Doesn't help/fix your code, it's just a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem for each tag option i do:

```
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.text = 'Santiago de Surco';
        opt.value = 'santiagodesurco';
        document.getElementById('dropdown3').options.add(opt);
```

That way I fix the problem, so the code works in IE9.